# Как с помощью средств ASP.NET MVC, html или css в одном из заголовков таблицы изменить направление текста?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день!

Есть некоторая таблица, которая выводится на веб-странице в следующем формате:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо задать для последних двух заголовков таблицы направление текста вертикальное (снизу вверх). Результат должен выглядеть примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно осуществить такое с помощью ASP.NET, html или css? Я нашел в css `writing-mode`, но он поддерживается только в IE (и то, не во всех версиях). И к тому же данное свойство не позволяет направить текст "снизу-вверх".

**UPD.** Также пробовал `transform: rotate(-90.0deg)`, но этого недостаточно, т.к. текст выходит за границы ячейки.

Comment: Можно попробовать `transform: rotate(90deg)`

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk я тоже так хотел, но есть одна проблема: после поворота текста он не вмещается в ячейку.  Если есть способ как-то его ужать относительно размеров ячейки, то меня устроит ваше решение.

Comment: Есть ещё экспериментальный https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation , но там пока не очень.